# My Notification listener app not saving notification in background

Tags: android, android-studio, notifications, android-notifications, background-process

I need to implement notification listener functionalities in my app. When android device get notification that should save in my Database. But my Notification service not working as background.
that's my Code

Manifest.xml

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.DeletedMessageRecovery">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service
        android:name = ".NotificationService"
        android:label = "@string/app_name"
        android:permission = "android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action
                android:name = "android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

</application>
```

NotificationService.java

```
public class NotificationService extends NotificationListenerService {

Context context ;

@Override
public void onCreate () {
    super .onCreate() ;
    context = getApplicationContext() ;
}

@Override
public void onNotificationPosted (StatusBarNotification sbn) {

    if (sbn.getPackageName().equals("com.whatsapp")) {


        if ((sbn.getNotification().flags & Notification.FLAG_GROUP_SUMMARY) != 0) {
            //Ignore the notification
        }
        else {

            Bundle extras = sbn.getNotification().extras;
            String title = extras.getString("android.title");
            String text = extras.getCharSequence("android.text").toString();
            long timee = sbn.getNotification().when;


            Log.i("time", String.valueOf(timee));
            Log.i("Title", title);
            Log.i("Text", text);

            Intent msgrcv = new Intent("Msg");
            msgrcv.putExtra("title", title);
            msgrcv.putExtra("text", text);
            msgrcv.putExtra("time", timee);

            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(msgrcv);




        }
    }

}
@Override
public void onNotificationRemoved (StatusBarNotification sbn) {
}
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {


private TextView txtView ;
ArrayList<String> listusr = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> listmsgg = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> timelist = new ArrayList<String>();
GridView gridView;
public static String usrname = "";

Data db;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    startService(new Intent(this, NotificationService.class));
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("Msg"));

    db = new Data(this);

    txtView = findViewById(R.id. textView ) ;
    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gdd);


    if (db.isTableExists(true)) {

        if (db.checkTable()) {
            txtView.setText("No message...!");
        } else {

            listusr = db.getAllData("Users","username");
            listmsgg = db.getAllData("Users", "LMsgg");
            timelist = db.getAllData("Users", "DateTime");


            GridAdapter adapter = new GridAdapter();
            gridView.setAdapter(adapter);


        }
    }
    else {
        txtView.setText("No Data Exist..!");
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.mainmenu, menu);
    return true;
}

public void settingClick(MenuItem item) {

    Intent intent = new Intent("android.settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS" ) ;
    startActivity(intent) ;

}


class GridAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listusr.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return listusr.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.singleuser, parent, false);
        TextView txtUSer = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.usrr);
        TextView txtmsgg = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ltext);
        TextView txtTimee = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.timee);


        txtUSer.setText(listusr.get(position));
        txtmsgg.setText(listmsgg.get(position));

        txtTimee.setText(timelist.get(position));

        return convertView;
    }
}



BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


        usrname = intent.getStringExtra("title");
        String text = intent.getStringExtra("text");
        long timee = intent.getLongExtra("time", 0);


        if (db.resultcheck(usrname)) {
                db.updateDataRelation(String.valueOf(timee), usrname, text);
            }
            else {
                db.insertData(String.valueOf(timee), usrname, text);
            }
            db.insertDataRelation(String.valueOf(timee), text);



    }
};
}
```

need help. I  want app that work as background

Comment: need answer this Question. ?

Comment: have you found an answer to this?